# ASP.NET MVC app: Debugging a function that returns "true" if input number is a Happy number using Lists vs Hashsets in array

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

So I'm working on an MVC view model that will tell a user if a given integer input is a Happy Number or not. As stated, the final code will sit in an MVC view model, but in the meantime, I've been checking the logic by debugging the code as a separate console app. I've got the console app working, but when I migrate the code back to the view model and then debug in the full application, literally nothing happens and IIS eventually times out the request. My view and controller implementations look solid (I'm leaving out that code for now), so I think I'm screwing up the logic in my actual model. Thoughts?

**The code explained in further detail:**
I'm new to OO programming, so for the sake of my own comprehension, I have split up the program into to two separate functions (Yes, I am aware this is bad practice, but it's homework). The first function (see below), which I've called "sumPowered", takes an integer input, separates the individual digits into an array, squares the individual digits, and returns the sum of the squared digits. Next, I have created a validation function called "isHappy" in which I call the preceding sumPowered function, pass through the parameters, generate a result array, and compare them to the happy number conditions.

To provide a clear outline, the first block of code below is the working code as it appears in my console app. The second block demonstrates how the code appears in the view model (doesn't work).

**EDIT:** I should have clarified that I am not producing any build errors or errors in the console view of Chrome's property inspector when I run the MVC code, yet the function did not work. I have since found a fix (answer post pending).

**CONSOLE APP**

```
  //CONSOLE APP
    namespace MoreCSharpPractice
    {
        class Program
        {
            static void Main(string[] args)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Enter a number");
                int number = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
                isHappy(number);

            }
            public static int sumPowered(int num, int pow)
            {
                int sum = 0;
                List<int> numsL = new List<int>();
                while (num > 0)
                {
                    numsL.Add(num % 10);
                    num = num / 10;
                }
                int[] nums = numsL.ToArray();
                for (int a = 0; a < nums.Length; a++)
                {
                    sum += Convert.ToInt32(Math.Pow(Convert.ToDouble(nums[a]), Convert.ToDouble(pow)));
                }

                return sum;
            }

            //HAPPY NUMBER
            //return true if 'number' is a happy number.
            private static void isHappy(int number)
            {
                List<int> sumArray = new List<int>();
                bool running = true;
                while (running)
                {
                    int result = sumPowered(number, 2);
                    if (result == 1)
                    {
                        running = false;
                        Console.WriteLine("Is a Happy Number!");
                    }
                    else if (sumArray.Contains(result))
                    {
                        running = false;
                        //return false;
                        Console.WriteLine("Is not a Happy Number");
                    }
                    number = result;
                    sumArray.Add(result);
                }
                //return true;
                Console.ReadKey();
            }
        }
    }
```

**MVC CODE**

```
//VIEW MODEL CODE: SUM POWERED FUNCTION
    public static int sumPowered(int num, int pow)
    {
        int sum = 0;
        List<int> numsL = new List<int>();
        while (num > 0)
        {
            numsL.Add(num % 10);
            num = num / 10;
        }
        int[] nums = numsL.ToArray();
        for (int i = 0; i < nums.Length; i++)
        {
            sum += Convert.ToInt32(Math.Pow(Convert.ToDouble(nums[i]), Convert.ToDouble(pow)));
        }
        return sum;
    }

    //VIEW MODEL CODE: HAPPY NUMBER FUNCTION
    //return true if 'number' is a happy number.
   private static bool isHappy(int number)
    {
        List<int> sumArray = new List<int>();
        while (true)
        {
            int result = sumPowered(number, 2);
            if (result == 1)
            {
                return true;
            }
            else if (sumArray.Contains(result))
            {
                return false;
            }
            number = result;
            sumArray.Add(result);
        }

   }
```

Comment: By "View Model" do you mean "Controller"? The models are just containers of data and shouldn't contain business logic.

Comment: You need to describe the symptoms of the problem you're seeing. You only say that you think you're screwing up the logic, but you're not saying why you think that. "Things break down" is not a good problem description.

Comment: @SamuelDavidson my understanding of where application-specific vs. domain logic should live in MVC is best described by [Yusubov](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/165444/where-to-put-business-logic-in-mvc-design/165446#165446)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Determined that this wasn't a logic error but instead a performance issue while running debug. By changing the data type of variable `sumArray` in my `isHappy()` function from a `List` to a `HashSet`, I was able to run through the function without having to iterate through an entire list when invoking `else if (sumArray.Contains(result))`.

```
  //HAPPY NUMBER
        //return true if 'number' is a happy number.
       private static bool isHappy(int number)
        {
            HashSet<int> sumArray = new HashSet<int>();
            while (true)
            {
                int result = sumPowered(number, 2);
                if (result == 1)
                {
                    return true;
                }
                else if (sumArray.Contains(result))
                {
                    return false;
                }
                number = result;
                sumArray.Add(result);
            }
       }
```